# hdiutil not responsive when installing DMG files using homebrew-cask

Tags: macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask, hdiutil

I encountered a weird problem installing DMG packaged apps on MacOS. Below is what I know, but I still have no clue what is wrong.

I tried to install things like `skype` or `inkscape` on MacOS (10.13.4) using

```
brew cask install skype --debug
```

But it hangs, with the following output.

```
==> Hbc::Installer#install
==> Printing caveats
==> Hbc::Installer#fetch
==> Satisfying dependencies
==> Downloading
==> Downloading https://inkscape.org/gallery/item/11269/Inkscape-0.92.2-1-x11-10.7-x86_64.dmg
Already downloaded: /Users/hwwu/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/inkscape--0.92.2-1,11269.dmg
==> Downloaded to -> /Users/hwwu/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/inkscape--0.92.2-1,11269.dmg
==> Verifying download
==> Determining which verifications to run for Cask inkscape
==> Checking for verification class Hbc::Verify::Checksum
==> 1 verifications defined
Hbc::Verify::Checksum
==> Running verification of class Hbc::Verify::Checksum
==> Verifying checksum for Cask inkscape
==> SHA256 checksums match
==> Installing Cask inkscape
==> Hbc::Installer#stage
==> Extracting primary container
==> Determining which containers to use based on filetype
==> Checking container class Hbc::Container::Pkg
==> Checking container class Hbc::Container::Ttf
==> Checking container class Hbc::Container::Otf
==> Checking container class Hbc::Container::Air
==> Checking container class Hbc::Container::Cab
==> Checking container class Hbc::Container::Dmg
==> Executing: ["/usr/bin/hdiutil", "imageinfo", "/Users/hwwu/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/inkscape--0.92.2-1,11269.dmg"]
==> Using container class Hbc::Container::Dmg for /Users/hwwu/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/inkscape--0.92.2-1,11269.dmg
==> Executing: ["/usr/bin/hdiutil", "attach", "-plist", "-nobrowse", "-readonly", "-noidme", "-mountrandom", "/var/tmp/d20180606-25779-z2yt24", "/Users/hwwu/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/inkscape--0.92.2-1,11269.dmg"]
```

So I tried the last line manually

```
/usr/bin/hdiutil attach -verbose -debug -plist -nobrowse -readonly -noidme -mountrandom /var/tmp/ /Users/hwwu/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/skype--8.22.0.2.dmg
```

And it hangs and shows

```
calling DIHLDiskImageAttach with
mount-type: randomized
drive-options:
force-idme: false
quiet: false
mount-point: file:///var/tmp/
verbose: true
debug: true
read-only: true
agent: hdiutil
skip-idme: true
image-options:
main-url: file:///Users/hwwu/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/skype--8.22.0.2.dmg
2018-06-06 11:14:26.858 hdiutil[27659:45934024] DIHLDiskImageAttach: input dictionary {
    agent = hdiutil;
    debug = 1;
    "drive-options" =     {
    };
    "force-idme" = 0;
    "image-options" =     {
    };
    "main-url" = "file:///Users/hwwu/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/skype--8.22.0.2.dmg";
    "mount-point" = "file:///var/tmp/";
    "mount-type" = randomized;
    quiet = 0;
    "read-only" = 1;
    "skip-idme" = 1;
    verbose = 1;
}
2018-06-06 11:14:26.859 hdiutil[27659:45934024] DIHLDiskImageAttach: disabling legacy image format attach
2018-06-06 11:14:26.859 hdiutil[27659:45934024] DIHLDiskImageAttach: newImagekeys = {
    "legacy-disabled" = 1;
}
2018-06-06 11:14:26.859 hdiutil[27659:45934024] DIHLDiskImageAttach: creating DIHelperProxy
2018-06-06 11:14:26.859 hdiutil[27659:45934024] with dictionary: {
    agent = hdiutil;
    debug = 1;
    "drive-options" = <62706c69 73743030 d0080000 00000000 01010000 00000000 00010000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0009>;
    "force-idme" = 0;
    "image-options" = <62706c69 73743030 d101025f 100f6c65 67616379 2d646973 61626c65 6409080b 1d000000 00000001 01000000 00000000 03000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 1e>;
    "main-url" = "file:///Users/hwwu/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/skype--8.22.0.2.dmg";
    "mount-point" = "file:///var/tmp/";
    "mount-type" = randomized;
    operation = DIHelperAttach;
    quiet = 0;
    "read-only" = 1;
    "skip-idme" = 1;
    verbose = 1;
}
2018-06-06 11:14:26.859 hdiutil[27659:45934024] [DIHelperProxy alloc]
2018-06-06 11:14:26.863 hdiutil[27659:45934024] [DIHelperProxy alloc] returning self 0x7fddcf407ba0, retainCount 1
2018-06-06 11:14:26.863 hdiutil[27659:45934024] DIHLDiskImageAttach: running DIHelperProxy
2018-06-06 11:14:26.864 hdiutil[27659:45934024] [DIHelperProxy performOperationReturning] entry
2018-06-06 11:14:26.864 hdiutil[27659:45934024] [DIHelperProxy performOperationReturning] detaching thread
2018-06-06 11:14:26.865 hdiutil[27659:45934029] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] entry
2018-06-06 11:14:26.865 hdiutil[27659:45934029] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] setting up server
2018-06-06 11:14:26.865 hdiutil[27659:45934029] [DIHelperProxy threadSetupServer] entry
2018-06-06 11:14:26.865 hdiutil[27659:45934029] XPC: created intermediaryConnection connection
2018-06-06 11:14:26.865 hdiutil[27659:45934029] XPC: creating helperconnection connection
```

Both `brew doctor` and `brew cask doctor` show no sign of problem. I also disabled LittleSnitch firewall. I have no anti-virus programs installed. Installing other DMG related packages all have this problem. I haven't been able to install anything for sometime. It seems to me that this is a `hdiutil` or system problem, instead of any homebrew bug. `sudo` doesn't help, it somehow shows "Unknown UID".

However, by double clicking on a downloaded DMG, it just works as it should be, and installation is just fine.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh...

It turns out that I was using an outdated iTerms window, where the user id is obsolete. `hdiutil` fails silently because of this wrong uid.

It is the `sudo` wrong uid that rings the bell. Hope whoever read this question don't run into my problem.